# How can I change my font to Raleway in letter class?

Tags: fonts

I'm somewhat a novice in writing letters in LaTeX, and I would like to shy away from the standard Times New Roman font. Specifically, I would like to use Raleway font, but I have no idea how to implement this. I've researched, but can't find anything.

Comment: Um, the standard font for LaTeX certainly is *not* Times New Roman, what is this blasphemy!? ;) On a serious note, welcome to the site! For arbitrary font selection, you're probably gonna wanna look at XeTeX, this will enable you to use most fonts you have on your computer directly. The documentation [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetex?lang=en) is pretty helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need the [raleway-package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/raleway) on your system. If you don't have a complete LaTeX-installation – in which case you don't have to do anything – you can use the package manager of your distribution to install the package.

Then you can just use the raleway font by putting `\usepackage{raleway}` in your preamble. Like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{raleway}                      % Load raleway font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Set sans serif for document
\begin{document}
    Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Et voilà:

[image]